# MediaWiki Local Extension Link

Tags: hyperlink, mediawiki, local

I installed MediaWiki locally. Everything worked but I needed a functionality to link files from our file server. I stumbled upon an extension called Extension:NetworkLink which provides this functionality. You just have to add filepath in your wikipage and it should work. My problem is that I the path of my local wiki installation "http://localhost/w/index.php/" is addedd to filepath and then the link does not work. I tried to edit the url manipulation in the PHP file to cut it out but it does not work. Here is the edited code:

```
<?php

function linkExtension() {
    global $wgParser;
    $wgParser->setHook( "link", "renderlink" );
}

# The callback function for converting the input text to HTML output
function renderlink( $loc='', $argv=array() ) {
    global $wgOut, $wgTitle, $wgParser;

    $loc = htmlspecialchars($loc);

    $pos = strrpos($loc, "/");
    if ($pos != false) 
    {
        $loc = substr($loc, $pos + 1);  
    } 

    switch( strtoupper( $argv['TARGET'] ) ) {
    case "SELF":
       $out = "<a href=\"{$loc}\" target=\"_self\">$loc</a>";
       break;
    case "TOP":
       $out = "<a href=\"{$loc}\" target=\"_top\">$loc</a>";
       break;
    case "PARENT":
       $out = "<a href=\"{$loc}\" target=\"_parent\">$loc</a>";
       break;
    default:
       $out = "<a href=\"{$loc}\" target=\"_blank\">$loc</a>";
    }

    return $out;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another better solution. First install the FF-plugin LocalLink. Then add the MediaWiki Extension:FileProtocolLinks. After this you can add links in your wiki to local files or shares on your network like this:

LAN: `<file>\\Fileserver\Directory1\Directory2\MyFile.zip</file>`

Local: `<file>C:/Directory1/Directory2/MyFile.zip</file>`